# Como controlar quando os dados do localstorage expiram?

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage

Estou armazenando alguns dados no **localstorage** do navegador e gostaria de definir uma data de expiração para esses dados, mas não acho uma forma de **controlar quando esses dados expiram**.

Esses dados possuem algum controle sobre quando eles serão descartados?

Quando é que o navegador vai descartar esses dados? Se o HD do usuário ficar cheio, se passarem alguns meses? Se o HD queimar? hehe... esquece o HD queimando.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aparentemente não é possível definir a expiração para dados no `localStorage`.

## Uso constante de armazenamento

Geralmente você vai ter um conjunto finito de itens armazenados e vai atualizá-los quando necessário, mantendo o uso mais ou menos constante. Neste cenário, você não teria que se preocupar com o limite.

## Solução para simular a expiração dos dados

Se você quiser verificar se os dados são antigos, o melhor que você pode fazer é armazenar a data e hora em que você os criou e, quando recuperá-los, verificar se os mesmos estão dentro do tempo aceitável.

Exemplo:

```js
var object = {value: "value", timestamp: new Date().getTime()}
localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(object));
```

Depois, recupere o item e verifique a data:

```js
var object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key")),
    timestamp = object.timestamp,
    value = object.value;

verificarValidade(timestamp);
```

Fonte do exemplo: [resposta no StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/when-do-items-in-html5-local-storage-expire)

## Removendo itens que não são mais usados

Os problemas começam se você estiver apenas adicionando **novos** itens indiscriminadamente.

Se você sabe que algum item não vai mais ser usado, pode usar o [`localStorage.removeItem(key)`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-removeitem) para liberar o espaço de armazenamento.

Além disso, caso tenha armazenado a data como indicado no tópico anterior, pode também iterar sobre os itens armazenados usando [`length`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-length) e [`key(n)`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-key) e remover os que forem antigos.

## Armazenamento temporário usando `sessionStorage`

Caso o escopo dos itens armazenados não precise perdurar quando o usuário fechar a aba ou o navegador pode-se usar também o [`sessionStorage`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-sessionstorage). Ele possui a mesma *interface* do `localStorage`, porém, segundo a especificação, os dados são removidos após o usuário encerrar a "sessão" ou "contexto" do navegador.

Segue um exemplo de uso:

```js
//save a value
sessionStorage.setItem("name", "Seu nome");

//retrieve item
var name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");

//get the key name for the first item
var key = sessionStorage.key(0);

//remove the key
sessionStorage.removeItem(key);

//check how many key-value pairs are present
var count = sessionStorage.length;
```

Fonte do exemplo [aqui](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/).

Comment: Então quer dizer que eu não posso ir colocando o que quiser no localstorage... como faço para saber então se ele está cheio?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Em tese, você não deveria ir apenas adicionando infinitamente coisas no *LocalStorage*. Geralmente você vai querer atualizar esses itens lá, por exemplo. Por outro lado, se você sabe que algum item não vai mais ser usado, pode usar o `localStorage.removeItem(key);`  para retirar e liberar o espaço.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Atualizei a resposta com mais algumas ideias.

Comment: Pesquisando um pouco mais, cheguei ao conhecimento do `sessionstorage`, que expira no fechamento da janela/tab do navegador. No meu caso especificamente, isso foi a melhor solução... coloca um adendo ai na sua resposta sobre sessionstorage, que vai ficar bem completa.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Obrigado pela dica. Reformulei a resposta por completo. Se o `sessionStorage` atender ao que você precisa vai ser bem mais fácil lidar com volume de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de variar de acordo com o Browser, o LocalStorage possui um tamanho limite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500713/html5-localstorage-size

Não sei se existe algum meio de limpá-lo automático. Desconfio que tenha que ser manual mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

O localstorage só apagando quando expira ou o usuário limpa manualmente.

> localStorage manterá o dado gravado até que ele seja removido diretamente, você poderá fechar o navegador, reiniciar o computador e os dados ainda estarão lá. --
>   [Fonte](http://tableless.com.br/web-storage-html5/)

A maneira de validar é igual os cookie, se não existir é poque foram apagados.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente não tem data de expiração para esses dados, o que você pode fazer é controlar por javascript quando o usuário acessar a aplicação você verifica se já está na hora de expirar o dado, e faz a recarga, ou somente removeria a informação.

Você pode [JStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) que tem o método setTTL(key, ttl) que por sua vez usa o setTimeout, mas se você deseja usar essa "expiração" igual cookie teria que ser desenvolvido.